# How to use paho library with angular

Tags: angularjs, websocket, mqtt, paho

I'm wondering how can I use paho which is a Javascript library uses WebSockets to connect to an MQTT server with AngularJS ?

Comment: I an quite a noob at angular but I think that you can call with no problem functions from a library inside angular, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please update your question with more detail of what exactly you want to do with Angular and Paho e.g. send a message on a button push? subscribe to a topic and update on message?

Comment: check this out. https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket

I have the same doubt that you have. 
As so i am analizing this already angularjs websocket to understand how to integrate mqtt on it.

Answer (score -1):

I would wrap the Paho Client in an angular factory, do you can use the same instance throughout your app.

A nice example could be found [HERE](https://github.com/bipol/angular-paho)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Updated with explanation.

Comment: You need to include a lot more detail with the link